# FileIOPermission fails when there is a '~' in the path. Why?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, file-permissions

I'm catching the following error in a publishing script (VB.Net) I'm running:

> Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

The code that fails is:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(path, content, False)
```

It runs fine for most of the files but some have a '~' in the path and those ones are all failing. Any ideas?

**Just to clarify:**
I am using the full path an example of the path I am having problems with is **"c:/websites/xml/myfile~test.xml"** the ones that work are **"c:/websites/xml/myfiletest2.xml"**

Answer (score 0):

How are you generating `path`? All of these work correctly for me:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(Server.MapPath("~test~1.xml"), "test", False)
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(Server.MapPath("~test2.xml"), "test", False)
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~"), "test~3.xml"), "test", False)
```

Comment: third option. was working up to now - the hosting company is looking into it but i thought there might be a coding reason why it is throwing the error

Comment: Can you upload a file with a tilde in the path to your host?